# Bizarre Undeclared Variable Compiler Error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

**Problem:** The compiler declares a seemingly nonsensical error that a local variable in a class member function "was not declared in this scope". The code shown below is a simplified implementation of the original function, and somehow it still triggers the same error. Furthermore, the error disappears whenever I rename the variable (in each place it's used) and resumes as soon as I change the variable back to its original name ("minor"). I don't understand this behavior and can't find any information/posts on what would cause a compiler to do this. Could someone kindly offer suggestions on what might be wrong? Is it indicative of a major bug somewhere else in my code (e.g. the Matrix class definition)?

**Details:** I'm compiling on Linux Mint 18 using g++ on Makefiles generated by CMake. I've tried with and without a variety of compiler options (e.g. -O2, -Wall, etc.), and the result is unchanged. I've previously compiled and ran a slightly earlier version of this code/project on Windows 7 using MinGW and a self-written Makefile with no problems. I'm happy to provide additional details upon request.

**Modified/minimalist code snippet from Matrix.cpp:**

```
Matrix Matrix::BuildCofactorMatrix() const {
    double minor (0.0);
    minor = 1.0;
    return Matrix(height_, width_);
}
```

**Warning message:**

> /*PATH-TO-PROJECT-ROOT*/src/Matrix.cpp: In member function ‘Matrix Matrix::BuildCofactorMatrix() const’:
>   /*PATH-TO-PROJECT-ROOT*/src/Matrix.cpp:1123:5: error: ‘minor’ was not declared in this scope
>        minor = 1.0;

**2017-08-21 Edit:**
I removed unnecessary code and created a truly "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable" example of the problem. For me, the error seems to be a function of the iostream library. If I remove the iostream inclusion, the problem seems to disappear. However, the error also depends on the c++ standard used for compiling. When I specify that g++ use, for example, -std=c++11 or -std=c++14, the problem persists, but once I remove the specification (i.e. g++ -c Matrix.cpp), the error disappears. By the way, I'm using g++ 4:5.3.1-1ubu.

Unless I'm missing something, I can't find any macros in iostream, istream, ostream, or ios that mention the term "minor", but perhaps it's further up the inclusion chain...?

**Matrix.hpp:**

```
#ifndef MATRIX_HPP
#define MATRIX_HPP

class Matrix {
    public:
        void BuildCofactorMatrix() const;
};

#endif
```

**Matrix.cpp:**

```
#include "Matrix.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void Matrix::BuildCofactorMatrix() const {
    double minor (0.0);
    minor = 0.0;
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to prepare a [MCVE] please.

Comment: *Modified/minimalist code snippet from Matrix.cpp:* -- No it isn't.  Who knows what ill-advised macro or similar construct you may have lurking in your program to cause this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can replicate the problem by adding  `#define minor(x) (x)` before the function.

The macro matches `minor(0.0)` but not `minor` without the "parameter".

The line

```
double minor (0.0);
```

would be replaced by

```
double (0.0);
```

which is a valid, but useless, type cast.

So, go look for some evil macro in one of the include files.

Comment: After simplifying the code and searching for predefined macros, I found a Q/A which addressed the issue <stackoverflow.com/questions/22240973>.